# Flutter display sql data in ListTile instead of DataCell

Tags: flutter, dart

I am displaying a list of data fetched from my sql database using `DataCell`, but I don't really like how it looks and want to switch it to display it using `ListTile`, this is the code that I am using to display it using `DataCell`:

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: DataTable(
          columns: [
            DataColumn(
              label: Text(''),
            )
          ],
          rows: _chatUsers
              .map(
                (user) => DataRow(cells: [
                  DataCell(
                    Text(user.firstNameUser),
                    // Add tap in the row and populate the
                    // textfields with the corresponding values to update
                    onTap: () {
                      // Set the Selected employee to Update
                      _selectedUser = user;
                      setState(() {

                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ]),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) widget for this.
There is a lot explained in that API reference section, I think you will be able to rework you app after reading.

So you will have a `ListView` with the `children`property set to smth like

```
_chatUsers
              .map(
                (user) => 
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(user.firstNameUser),
                    // Add tap in the row and populate the
                    // textfields with the corresponding values to update
                    onTap: () {
                      // Set the Selected employee to Update
                      _selectedUser = user;
                      setState(() {

                      });
                    },
                  ),
              )
              .toList()
```

Comment: ok, thanks. I'm gonna read it. But do you know how will I be able to use the `_chatUsers.map((user))`?

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out.