# Flutter add separation lines to ListTile

Tags: flutter, dart

Following to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63018841/flutter-display-sql-data-in-listtile-instead-of-datacell), I was able to display all the data from the database in a ListTile Widget, but how can I add some lines to separate it.

```
return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: int.parse(_resultLength),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Column(
            children: _Users
                .map(
                  (user) => ListTile(
                    leading: Container(
                      height: 47,
                      width: 47,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(user.imageLink),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    title: Text(user.firstName + " " + user.lastName),
                    /*onTap: () {
                //_selectedUser = user;
                setState(() {});
              },*/
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          );
        },
      );
```

I have tried to use `Divider(),` after the `ListTile` and also changing the `ListView.builder` to `ListView.separated`. However, the `children: _Users.map((user) =>)` and the `.toList()` is preventing the separator to work. Is there a way to add it without altering much the current code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little strange what you're doing... you're not supposed to use the `ListView` to build a big single item.

I assume that `_resultLength` is the length of `_Users` list. Instead of building a single item containing the entire `_Users` list you should try something like this

```
return ListView.separated(
  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(height: 1),
  itemCount: int.parse(_resultLength),
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    var user = _Users[index];
    return ListTile(
      leading: Container(
        height: 47,
        width: 47,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage(user.imageLink),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      title: Text(user.firstName + " " + user.lastName),
      /*onTap: () {
            //_selectedUser = user;
            setState(() {});
          },*/
    );
  },
```

You will be able to use `ListView.separated` with this approach,

Comment: Thank you @Claudio Redi, your code worked fine. Yes, the `_resultLength` is the length of `_users`.